# Understanding need for a selector in dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I was trying to learn how to create drop down menu from CSS tricks. This is code they have:

```
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

css

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  font-family: monospace;
}

ul {
  background: darkorange;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  color: #fff;
  background: darkorange;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
  
li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover {
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li ul {
  background: orange;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

What I don't understand from above is why they need the following selector:

```
ul li ul:hover
```

**Because when I remove it the menu still works**. Can someone explain why? Which is the correct selector?

Here is demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-aftbkv?file=style.css

Article link:
https://css-tricks.com/solved-with-css-dropdown-menus/

Comment: How old is the example you are referencing to?

Comment: @QuentinAlbert I will update question with link to article

Answer (score 0):

the hover selector means: when the mouse is on that element, something is going to happen. it adds some functionality.

has u see the elements of the dropdown menu they have `display:none` and on hover they set their display to `display:block` appering them.

If u delete all the hover it will not work! maybe is because u deleted them and not save the file or maybe the cache, but without :hover will not be functionality.

Comment: delete "ul li ul:hover" and it will still work, check.

Comment: yes right, in this case it is not necessary this line "ul li ul:hover", it is adding the hover to the inner ul but is not doing nothing to it, kind strange, maybe in a future he will add a dropdown also to each a tag, who knows